# increase tableview height when outer scrollview begin to scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, tableview

I have a scrollview contains all views on the viewcontroller including a tableview. all views are scrolled like this :

[image]

but I want that the tableview stay at buttom of page and just increase its height like this :

[image]

I changed all constrains and googled but I couldnot find solution to this.How and Where I can increase table height when scrollview scrolls?

Comment: The two blue buttons on the bottom should be inside a UIView. You should add a vertically alignment constrain between the UIView and the bottom of the UITableView with priority 1000. If this doesn't do the work screen shot us the constraints that you have added

Comment: yes blue buttons are out of scrollview.but table view is in the scrollview.Should I put tableview out of scrollview too?

Comment: Provide some more code. Where are you increase the tableView height?

Comment: @Vishal16 I didnt code to increase height yet.I dont know how and where to increase height!

Comment: @maral you should add a constraint to the have equal bottoms the tableview.bottom with the scrollview.bottom, and the scrollview.bottom with the UIView that contains the 2 blue buttons

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ.thanks for your comment but visha's solution solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase table size with respect to scrollView contantSize in `viewDidLayoutSubView()` method

Provide a fixed height constraint to UITableView in storyboard or xib. Make an outlet for that constraint

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super .viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.constraintTableViewHeight.constant = self.scrollView.ContentSize.height
}
```

Hope it help. Happy codding:)

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: Always Welcome :)